# How does the "Handling Mobs" rule work with Advantage & Disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage, optional-rules

How should I modify the "Mob attacks" table (DMG 250) when the attacking mob has an advantage? Isn't a flat +5 bonus too generous?

Comment: related: [how does rolling two dice and taking the higher affect the average outcome?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14690/23970)

Answer (score 5):

The numbers in the DMG result from calculating the probability of a hit and then seeing how many attacks are needed to produce one hit on average. For example if a creature needs to roll 17 to hit, it has a 20% chance or 1 in 5. So if 5 creatures attack 1 will hit in average. If you make the same calculations with advantage (rounding 1/chance to hit) you get this scale:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|} 
  \text{d20 roll needed} & \text{Attackers per hit} \\ \hline
\ 1-10 & 1 \\ \hline
\ 11-16 & 2 \\ \hline
\ 17 & 3 \\ \hline
\ 18 & 4 \\ \hline
\ 19 & 5 \\ \hline
\ 20 & 10 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

With Disadvantage:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|} 
  \text{d20 roll needed} & \text{Attackers per hit} \\ \hline
\ 1-3 & 1 \\ \hline
\ 4-8 & 2 \\ \hline
\ 9-10 & 3 \\ \hline
\ 11 & 4 \\ \hline
\ 12 & 5 \\ \hline
\ 13 & 6 \\ \hline
\ 14 & 8 \\ \hline
\ 15 & 11 \\ \hline
\ 16 & 16 \\ \hline
\ 17 & 25 \\ \hline
\ 18 & 44 \\ \hline
\ 19 & 100 \\ \hline
\ 20 & 400 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

If you compare this with +5/-5 you will see that it the case of Advantage the flat bonus would be much more [ehem] advantageous for mobs with a low chance of hitting. Needing a 20 would become needing a 15. The DMG would then give a hit per 4 attackers where the full calculation shows you would need 10. Also if you apply -5 for Disadvantage, a mob that needs 16 or more to hit would have zero chance. This is not really a practical concern as 16 or more enemies can rarely surround a PC, but still a theoretical difference.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, I think it comes down to consider a mob as double their number for advantage, or half their number for disadvantage.

With this method though, in some cases in which a mob has advantage, the hits may exceed the total creature in the mob, so be aware and tune it down to a number of hits equivalent to the total of creatures in the mob.