# Dealing with new rules as a new Player

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

So I'm a beginner to D&D.  I like the character creation and stuff.  My DM keeps changing around things and I'm getting a bit confused.

Example: Advantage/Disadvantage is now +5 and -5 respectively instead of rolling twice

I am now told that I cannot dual-wield rapiers of all things purely because they said so.  I'm a newer Player so maybe I am in the wrong here.

Comment: It seems to me you have multiple, separate questions. It would be better to focus on just one in this question. You are welcome to post as many questions as you like. Also, please clarify your problems, because I have a hunch that your DM adheres to the rules correctly.

Comment: The comments aren't the place for asking and answering questions. Please just [edit] the question to be one question, and then the question post and answer posts can be used for the question and its answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your DM is new to 5e as well.

1. I'll start with dual wielding.  (Two Weapon Fighting)

   You cannot dual wield weapons unless they are both light weapons.  If you look at the weapon table on page 46 of the basic rules, you will see that the rapier does not have the *light* property.

   > Light. A light weapon is small and easy to handle, making it ideal for
   >   use when fighting with two weapons. See the rules for two-weapon
   >   fighting in chapter 9. (Baic Rules, p. 46)

   The rule on Two Weapon Fighting is available to any character of any class.

   > Two-Weapon Fighting
   >   When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand. You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative. If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon, instead of making a melee attack with it. (Basic Rules, p. 74)

   If your DM allows feats (they are an optional rule) you can take the feat *dual wielder*, which in addition to increasing your AC by 1 while dual wielding also allows you to dual wield non-light weapons such as longswords and rapiers.

   This differs from other editions of D&D which merely penalized dual wielding.
2. Then the next rule regarding advantage/disadvantage,

   Advantage and Disadvantage are essentially a +/-5 bonus/penalty if you need an average roll (it is larger/smaller as you need to hit a lower/higher DC). Is this an optional rule to save rolling time?  Not sure to be honest.

   I personally roll two d20s and the damage die when I have advantage, as written in the rules.

   > When you have either advantage or disadvantage, you roll a second d20 when you make the roll. Use the higher of the two rolls if you have advantage, and use the lower roll if you have disadvantage. For example, if you have disadvantage and roll a 17 and a 5, you use the 5. If you instead have advantage and roll those numbers, you use the 17.  More detailed rules for advantage and disadvantage are presented in chapter 7. (Basic Rules, p. 4)

Comment: I added in a few rules citations for you, from the basic rules.  You can include PHB references as you deem appropriate.

Comment: To be totally pedantic, you can hold one one-handed weapon in each hand, but you can't attack with both unless they meet the criteria specified above.

Answer (score 1):

> Advantage is now +5 and -5 Respectively, instead of rolling twice

In previous editions it was common practice to add 4 to a roll that had "advantage" and reduce 4 to a roll that had "disadvantage". RAW 5e does not have that rule [except when used for passive ability checks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks).  For a detailed illustration of how advantage and disadvantage work, [see this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14690/22566).

> Now i cannot duel wield rapiers of all things purely because they said so.

It's not because they said so, it's because it's the rules. You can only dual wield weapons if they have the "Light" property, which a rapier has not. If you want to use a rapiers, you'll have to take the "Dual Wielder" feat.

Comment: "RAW 5e does not have that rule" - Not for active checks or attack rolls, but for [passive checks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks) it does. A character gets a +5 bonus or a -5 penalty to a passive check if it would have advantage/disadvantage on the associated active check. That may be where the DM got this idea.

Comment: I mentioned the Dual Wielder feat and they shot that down too. Basically anything with a D8 or higher they banned me from using.

Comment: @LorialVaris Is it possible that the DM is overreacting to your character dominating combat? Was every foe dying moments after meeting your PC's mighty paired rapiers of doom?

Comment: @Lorial Varis what level is your character? If it's a high elf, it isn't even eligible for that feat until level 4, if feats are allowed in your game.

Comment: Anthony, I edited in a few clarifications, please review to make sure that you are happy with them.