# The Passive Wisdom (Perception) score of my character on D&D Beyond seems too high

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, paladin, dnd-beyond

[I just made a 7th-level Dragonborn Vengeance Paladin character on D&D Beyond.](https://ddb.ac/characters/12292880/wxddvG)

It says his Passive Wisdom (Perception) is 18, but I don't understand how they calculated that number.

The character has a Wisdom score of 10 (a +0 modifier). He is proficient in Perception. His Proficiency Bonus is +3.

Shouldn't his passive Perception score be 10 + 0 + 3 = 13? Why does his sheet say 18?

Comment: The link to your character sheet does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[The D&D Beyond site is adding a +5 to your passive Perception due to your Sentinel Shield giving you advantage.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/7584-sentinel-shield-and-passive-perception)

From the SRD/basic rules on [passive checks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks):

> A passive check is a special kind of ability check that doesn’t involve any die rolls. Such a check can represent the average result for a task done repeatedly, such as searching for secret doors over and over again, or can be used when the GM wants to secretly determine whether the characters succeed at something without rolling dice, such as noticing a hidden monster.
>
> Here’s how to determine a character’s total for a passive check:
>
> **10 + all modifiers that normally apply to the check**
>
> If the character has advantage on the check, add 5. For disadvantage, subtract 5. The game refers to a passive check total as a **score**.

Comment: Related: [How does rolling two d20 and taking the higher affect the average outcome?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14690/23970)

Comment: Note that the link to the character sheet does not appear to be working, so we cannot 'see' the Sentinel Shield.  This answer would be improved by citing the rules for a Sentinel Shield and replacing the link with a statement that the character was equipped with one.